# ASP.NET MVC 3 routing: prevent ~/home access?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, seo, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm fine with ~/ mapping to Home Index, and with ~/Blog mapping to Blog Index, but how do I prevent ~/Home mapping to Home Index as well? I don't want routes to be accessible from more than a single endpoint.

Similarly, how do I prevent every other "Index" action being accessible from both ~/Controller and ~/Controller/Index?

OK ~/
NO ~/Home
NO ~/Home/Index
OK ~/AnyOtherController
NO ~/AnyOtherController/Index

I guess the rule should be something like preventing any default actions to be accessible explicitly, and in the case of home also prevent it being accessible with just the controller.

Can this be done? Has it been done in the past? SO for instance doesn't do this (you can access either [here](https://stackoverflow.com/) or [there](https://stackoverflow.com/home)) and both render the home page; and they probably have a different default action name than "index", which possibly is probably an accessible route too.

Comment: This is very similar to a question I asked the the other day: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9974402/301-redirect-original-url-request-to-routed-url . I'm not saying its a duplicate as I think its slightly different, but I would be interested in knowing the answer to this too.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you don't want the routes accessible from more than one endpoint.

Comment: maybe look into using the `AttributeRouting` package from nuget so you can explicitly define all your routes...

Comment: @AnthonyPotts Having the same page accessible from multiple urls is SEO unfriendly, as it appears to be duplicate content and splits your PageRank between the urls.

Comment: @saluce - That's only an issue if you have links to multiple routes to the same page.  In an MVC with proper routing, the /Home/Index link will never appear on any page, thus Google won't know it exists, nor will any of your users.

Comment: Users manually entering full URLs won't change your rank on Google if you use `@Html.Action[Link]` on your page and not specify manually hand typed URLs that specify full URLs...

Comment: @saluce - Is that only true if those other endpoints are known and indexed by search engines?

Comment: @Anthony_Potts Yes, that is correct. And, as long as you make sure those alternate URLs are not used on your site, its unlikely anyone else will find them.

Comment: ActionLinks should prevent the issue but if you're that worried about the spiders and SEO, use the Canonical tag: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_link_element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implemented it like this in order for those routes to be regarded as 404 errors but still within my MVC application (in order for the custom errors view to take place):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// By not using .IgnoreRoute I avoid IIS taking over my custom error handling engine.
    /// </summary>
    internal static void RegisterRouteIgnores(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "IgnoreHome",
            "Home",
            new { controller = "Error", action = "NotFound" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "IgnoreIndex",
            "{controllerName}/Index/{*pathInfo}",
            new { controller = "Error", action = "NotFound" }
        );
```

This does allow access to Home/Index action through the use of `/home/{id}`, but I'm willing to live with that.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply declare that routing should not be applied to URLs that match there patterns. For example:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.Ignore("Home/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.Ignore("{controller}/Index");
}
```

A URL matching these routes would then be treated as a bare page, which of course will not exist.

Comment: He surely doens't want to ignore all other **Home** actions apart from **Index** so the first one has to be changed to `"Home"`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i was able to achieve what i think your asking.

```
// Portal Sections
        routes.MapRoute("Home",
                        "",
                        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" },
                        new[] { "Myapp.Portal.Controllers" });

        routes.MapRoute("About",
                        "about",
                        new { controller = "Home", action = "About" },
                        new[] { "Myapp.Portal.Controllers" });

        routes.MapRoute("Features",
                        "features",
                        new { controller = "Home", action = "Features" },
                        new[] { "Myapp.Portal.Controllers" });


        routes.MapRoute("Help",
                        "help",
                        new { controller = "Help", action = "Index" },
                        new[] { "Myapp.Portal.Controllers" });

        routes.MapRoute("Knowledgebase",
                        "help/kb",
                        new { controller = "Help", action = "Knowledgebase" },
                        new[] { "Myapp.Portal.Controllers" });
```

I can Access

- mysite.com
- mysite.com/about
- mysite.com/features
- mysite.com/help
- mysite.com/help/kb

but access is not available to

- mysite.com/home/about
- mysite.com/home/features

hope this help :)